# sorting multiple parent or child sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, tree

i have this table

```
id |   name   | parent 
26 |   one    | 20
20 |   two    | 14
14 | sub top1 | 1
17 | sub top2 | 1
31 |   six    | 17
1  |   top    | 0
```

if parent is 0 it's mean the highest level, and now i want to displaying from lower parent to highest parent , like this

```
1. top
-- 14. sub top1
---- 20. two
------ 26. one
-- 17. sub top2
---- 31. six
```

anyone can create query to this result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: mysql @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, name from table order 
by parent.
```

Comment: Not this, its just sort by parrent

Comment: Thats exactly what your question asked for. From lowest to highest parent.